# Start chain Tasks wait for result all of them in C#

Tags: c#, .net, async-await, task

What I need to start **chain** `Tasks` and wait for results of all of them.

```
List<int> myAsyncWork1()
List<int> myAsyncWork2()
List<int> myAsyncWork3()

var tasks = new Func<Task>[]
{
   () => myAsyncWork1(),
   () => myAsyncWork2(),
   () => myAsyncWork3()
};

await Task.WhenAll(tasks.Select(task => task()).ToArray()); //Async
```

How we can get `List<int>` of all methods when the all `Tasks` are **completed**?

Comment: The code you posted doesn't make sense. You show methods declared as returning `List<int>`, not `Task` or `Task<List<int>>`, and anonymous methods likewise returning `List<int>`, yet your array is `Func<Task>[]`. There doesn't appear to be any async going on at all. If there were, you could just store the `ToArray()` in a variable before passing it to `WhenAll()` and enumerate the tasks when they are done. Did you try anything like that? Please provide a good [mcve] that shows the actual context here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply use the result of `WhenAll`, for example:

```
Task<List<int>> work1() { ... }
Task<List<int>> work2() { ... }
Task<List<int>> work3() { ... }

async Task DoConcurrentWork()
{
    List<int>[] lists = await Task.WhenAll(work1(), work2(), work3());

    // use lists
}
```

Answer (score 2):

After you sure that all tasks completed, you can use `task.Result` property.

```
var tasksFunc = new Func<Task<List<int>>>[]
{
   () => myAsyncWork1(),
   () => myAsyncWork2(),
   () => myAsyncWork3()
};

var tasks = tasksFunc.Select(func => func());
await Task.WhenAll(tasks);

var allLists = tasks.Select(task => task.Result);
```

Comment: It seems like I have a problem to define `List<int> myAsyncWork1()` because it should return a task with List<int> so would ypu mind to help with that please?

Comment: `myAsyncWork1` should return type of `Task<List<int>>` in your case

Answer (score -1):

```
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var tasks = new List<Task<List<int>>>(){
            myAsyncWork1(),
            myAsyncWork2(),
            myAsyncWork3()
        };            

        var results = Task.WhenAll(tasks).Result;
        var numbers = results.SelectMany(x => x).ToList();
        Console.WriteLine(string.Join(" ", numbers.Select(x => x.ToString())));            
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    static Task<List<int>> myAsyncWork1()
    {            
        return Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine("MyAsyncWork1 started!");
            Thread.Sleep(300);
            Console.WriteLine("MyAsyncWork1 finished!");
            return new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3 };
        });
    }
    static Task<List<int>> myAsyncWork2()
    {
        return Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine("MyAsyncWork2 started!");
            Thread.Sleep(200);
            Console.WriteLine("MyAsyncWork2 finished!");
            return new List<int>() { 4, 5, 6 };
        }); ;
    }
    static Task<List<int>> myAsyncWork3()
    {
        return Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine("MyAsyncWork3 started!");
            Thread.Sleep(200);
            Console.WriteLine("MyAsyncWork3 finished!");
            return new List<int>() { 7, 8, 9 };
        });
    }
```